# Why ajax not able to fetch result?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post

I'm trying to fetch the result based on the user's selection in the select element. All it shows are just the `product_price1` when I try to select the other price range, the product price will not be able to change according to my selection. It will only show the first price of the product. I did place the id of each element in the correct way but it still not be able to work properly.
But i do not know where is the mistake i made, it just can't seems to fetch the correct result. Here are my codes:

```
<table class="table">
                <thead class="text-primary">
                  <th style=" position: sticky;top: 0; background: white";>
                    Product
                  </th>
                  <th style=" position: sticky;top: 0; background: white";>
                    Name
                  </th> 
                  <th style=" position: sticky;top: 0; background: white";>
                    Avaliable Stock
                  </th> 
                  <th style=" position: sticky;top: 0; background: white";>
                    Item Price(RM)
                  </th>
                  <th style=" position: sticky;top: 0; background: white";>
                   Insert Product Quantity
                  </th>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="products">
                  <?php
                    $product_id = $_REQUEST['id'];
                    $ids = explode(",",$product_id);
                    $ids = array_splice($ids, 0);
                 
                    foreach($ids as $product_id){
                    $sql = "SELECT *, products.id as product_id FROM products 
                    LEFT JOIN sellers ON products.seller_id = sellers.id 
                    WHERE products.id = '".$product_id."' 
                    ORDER BY product_created DESC  ";
                    $query = $conn->query($sql);
                    {
                    while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
                        $max = $row['product_stock'];
                  ?>

                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <?php echo $row['product_title']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <?php echo $row['product_stock']; ?> <?php echo $row['product_unit']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="number" name="cart_qty" step=".01" class="form-control text-center" required>
                    </div>
                    </td>
                     <td>       
                    <select name="price_range" id="price_range" class="form-control">
                        <option value="price_range1" selected><?php echo $row['weight_range1']; ?> <?php echo $row['product_unit']; ?></option>
                        <option value="price_range2"> <?php echo $row['weight_range2']; ?><?php echo $row['product_unit']; ?></option>
                        <option value="price_range3"><?php echo $row['weight_range3']; ?><?php echo $row['product_unit']; ?></option>
                        <option value="price_range4"><?php echo $row['weight_range4']; ?> <?php echo $row['product_unit']; ?></option>
                    </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <div class="col-12 my-auto">RM 
                <span id="product_price">
                    <input type="hidden" name="cart_price" value="<?php echo $row['product_price1']; ?>">
                    <?php echo $row['product_price1']; ?>
                </span>/<?php echo $row['product_unit']; ?>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  <?php
                      }
                  }
                }
                  ?>
                </tbody>
              </table>
```

I use AJAX method to POST the selection result, here are the codes

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#price_range').on('change', function() {
        var product_id = <?php echo $product_id ?>;
        var price_range = this.value;
        $.ajax({
            url: "includes/fetch-price.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                product_id: product_id,
                price_range: price_range
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function(result){
                $("#product_price").html(result);
                // console.log(price_range);
            }
        });
        
    });
});
</script>
```

Here is my fetch-price.php

```
<?php
require_once "../session.php";
$product_id = $_POST["product_id"];
$price_range = $_POST["price_range"];
$sql = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM products where id = '$product_id' ");
$scrow = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
if($price_range == 'price_range1')
{
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="cart_price" value="'.$scrow['product_price1'].'">', $scrow['product_price1'];
}
else if($price_range == 'price_range2')
{
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="cart_price" value="'.$scrow['product_price2'].'">', $scrow['product_price2'];
}
else if($price_range == 'price_range3')
{
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="cart_price" value="'.$scrow['product_price3'].'">', $scrow['product_price3'];
}
else if($price_range == 'price_range4')
{
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="cart_price" value="'.$scrow['product_price4'].'">',$scrow['product_price4'];
}

?>
```

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Answer (score 0):

While observing your code I can see that you have set

```
<select name="price_range" id="price_range" class="form-control">
```

inside the while and the real problem here is you have set

```
id="price_range"
```

and moving to you JS, in that you have set on change event on price_range

```
$('#price_range').on('change', function() {
```

and that selector while trace the id type (#), so as per JS rule in a page there should be unique selector otherwise the DOM events will act funny.

So now solution to your problem.

try to set

```
class="price_range"
```

instead of

```
 id="price_range"
```

and than in your JS set

```
$('.price_range').on('change', function() {
```

instead of

```
$('#price_range').on('change', function() {
```

I'm sure you will get the desired output :)